# SQL get the row with highest amount created first

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In a Mysql 5.5 database I have a table.
Originally, I just needed the first record with the highest amount.

```
bid
----------------------
id           int
personId     int
itemId       int
amount       double
tieBreak     boolean
updatedDate  datetime
```

DATA:

```
id       personId        itemId       amount     tiebreak     updatedDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           4             111          100          1         2013-08-26 09:00:00
2           5             111          100          0         2013-08-26 10:00:00
3           6             111          100          1         2013-08-26 11:00:00
...
4           24            222          200          0         2013-08-27 09:00:00
5           57            222          200          0         2013-08-27 10:00:00
6           12            222          200          0         2013-08-27 11:00:00
...
7           2             333          400          1         2013-08-27 11:00:00
8           7             333          300          1         2013-08-27 11:00:00
9           25            333          600          1         2013-08-27 11:00:00
```

I need the entire record for the oldest entry for each itemId in the table where amount equals the max amount for that item and items with tieBreak true (1) get priority over items with tiebreak false (0).

```
id       personId        itemId       amount     tiebreak     updatedDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           4             111          100          1         2013-08-26 09:00:00
4           24            222          200          0         2013-08-27 09:00:00
9           25            333          600          1         2013-08-27 11:00:00
```

1 because its the oldest record with tiebreak = 1 and the highest amount
4 because its the oldest record and everything else is equal
9 because its the highest amount

The closest I got was:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM bid a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bid a2 ON (a.itemId = a2.itemId AND a.amount < a2.amount)
WHERE a2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY tiebreak DESC, updatedDate ASC;
```

Which kind of works but pulls back ALL bids matching highest amount sorted...
I want ONLY the single oldest bid for each item where the highest amount and the highest value for tiebreak (1 or 0).  Meaning an amount of 10 with tiebreak 1 beats out an amount of 10 with tiebreak 0 even if the second bid came first.

Comment: An example with sample data and your desired output rows will be helpful to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of conditions is ideal for an `order by` clause.  Alas, you cannot select the first item for an item easily in MySQL.

But, there is a trick -- assuming that `id` uniquely identifies each row (and shame on you if such a column name doesn't have that property).  You can  use `group_concat()` with `order by` to order the `id`s by the conditions.  Then, `substring_index()` can get the first one.  Voila!  Almost as if MySQL supported `row_number()` (the ANSI standard way to do all of this).

Here is what the query looks like:

```
select bid.*
from (select itemid,
             substring_index(group_concat(id order by amount desc, updateddate asc, tiebreak desc), ',', 1) as id
      from bid
      group by itemid
     ) b join
     bid
     on b.itemid = bid.itemid and b.id = bid.id;
```

Comment: this only gets me a single record.  I want one for each itemId in the table.

Comment: @kasdega . . . It is fixed now.